# KQL Query to specify date range for Mailbox search?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I'm trying to verify some phone numbers using our exchange server with the following query to send the results to my inbox:

```
Get-Mailbox | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery “Body: '*XXX-XXX-XXXX*' OR '*XXX-XXX-XXXX*'" -TargetMailbox myusermailbox -TargetFolder verification
```

How do I specify a date range to search?  As the phone numbers usually appear in people's signatures, and I don't want to return every email they've ever sent, just recent ones.

I tried using the `-StartDate` and `-EndDate` but it failed with the error message:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '05-19-2014'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Search-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Search-Mailbox

Invoke-Command : Cannot write input as there are no more running pipelines
At C:\Users\administrator.UCPSAR\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Exchange\RemotePowerShell\exch2010.ucpsar.org\exch2010.ucpsa
r.org.psm1:43454 char:29
+             $scriptCmd = { & <<<<  $script:InvokeCommand `
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Command], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMoreInputWrite,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

I'm thinking maybe the parameters need to be specified as part of a KQL query but I'm uncertain of where to start.

Comment: Try using -StartDate and -EndDate in this format `-StartDate "5/19/2014"`

Comment: I tried that, still got an error.

Comment: Wait is `Body:'*stuff*' StartDate:'05/19/2014' EndDate:'05/20/2014'` a valid query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot in your SearchQuery:

-SearchQuery "Sent: > $('01/01/2012 00:00:00') AND Received: < $('01/31/2012 23:59:59') AND Body: ('*XXX-XXX-XXXX*' OR '*XXX-XXX-XXXX*')"

I don't have access to an environment to test this at the moment. This is modified from http://windowsitpro.com/exchange-server-2010/search-destroy-email-content-exchange-2010.

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for more information on forming AQS queries.

Comment: Hmm I wonder what the difference is between `queryable`, `retrievable`, and `searchable`? (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj983804%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Comment: See the notes at the bottom of that TechNet article.

Answer (score 0):

For a range you can use the '..' operator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911(v=office.15).aspx#kql_property_restriction_queries

So for example `-SearchQuery "Sent:(8/4/2014..8/5/2014)"`

Keep in mind if no time is specified it defaults to 12am so this query searches for everything sent from 8/4/2014 12:00am to 8/5/2014 12:00am